# Reference request - Two notions of suspension /loop space agree for simplicial objects

Tags: simplicial-stuff

In Goerss-Jardine they point out that there are two reasonable definitions of the (reduced) suspension of a simplicial set. One is the smash product with $S^1$ and one is the join with $S^0$, the "Kan suspension". They claim these two are homotopy equivalent, but I can't find a proof of this described in the book. I would like a reference for the homotopy equivalence of the definitions.

Likewise I am interested in a proof that their corresponding loop space adjoints are homotopy equivalent. Perhaps this follows by formal nonsense but even so I would like to see a reference for the formal nonsense.

I need explicit descriptions of the maps in both directions for computational reasons.

Comment: Goerss and Jardine write that "[they] have homeomorphic realizations". If you believe that then the homotopy equivalence can be realised by a zigzag, mediated by the singular set of the realisation.